# How to implement the equivalent of Java Generics Self-bounded types in C++ templates

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I have a small collection of algorithms in Java for playing multiple turn-based games, such as TicTacToe, Othello, Checkers, etc. I do it using Java Generics (self-bounded types) to be able to use the same algorithms without having to change them specifically for each game. The reason why I use self-bounded types is not shown here, but is is needed for the Evaluation Functions.

```
public interface Game<GAME extends Game<GAME>> {
    GAME copy();
    int getCurPlayer();
    ...
}

public class TicTacToe implements Game<TicTacToe> {
    ...
    @Override
    public TicTacToe copy() {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public int getCurPlayer() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Today, just for learning, I tried to move my Java code to C++, using C++ templates.

This was my approach, and obviously it didn't work.

Game.h

```
template <typename T>
class Game
{
    public:
        virtual T copy() const = 0;
        virtual int cur_player() const = 0;
        ...
};
```

TicTacToe.h

```
class TicTacToe : public Game<TicTacToe>
{
public:
    virtual TicTacToe copy() const;
    virtual int cur_player() const;
    ...
};
```

TicTacToe.cpp

```
TicTacToe TicTacToe::copy() {
    ...
}

int TicTacToe::cur_player() {
    ...
}
```

When I try to compile, the errors I get are:

```
out-of-line definition of 'copy' does not match any declaration in 'TicTacToe'

out-of-line definition of 'cur_player' does not match any declaration in 'TicTacToe'
```

...
and the same for each of the other pure virtual functions.

Comment: You never state what didn't work.

Comment: It's not obvious at all why that wouldn't work.  What is the problem you are having (compiler error?)

Comment: There's no use for "self-bounding types" in Java. Your code works just as well with `public interface Game<GAME>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definitions need to have `const` applied to them as well. The CRTP, as it's known in C++ (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) is perfectly valid C++.

However, there's no need for `virtual` here, the CRTP is used to statically dispatch functions and automatically implement functionality.

```
template <typename T>
class Game
{
    T& crtp_cast() { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
    const T& crtp_cast() const { return *static_cast<const T*>(this); }
public:
    T copy() const { return crtp_cast(); }
    int cur_player() const { return crtp_cast().cur_player(); }
    ...
};
```

Note that in this case, the derived class does *not* need to implement a "copy" function, as the copy constructor will automatically be called by "copy". However, in the general case, as templates are duck typed, it's unnecessary to do this kind of thing, and normally you'd just use a standard template. Unlike Java's Generics, C++'s templates have no relation to inheritance at all- the types you can instantiate with do not have to inherit from a common interface.

```
template<typename Game> void f(const Game& g) {
    std::cout << g.cur_player();
}
class X {
public:
    int cur_player() const { return 1; }
};
class Y {
public:
    int cur_player() const { return 2; }
};
int main() {
    f(X());
    f(Y());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! You were right, I was just missing the `const` in the definitions.

Comment: The cast is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using generics/templates, I would just pass around a pointer-to-Game from copy and such and then dynamic cast it down if you really need to.

For example:

Game.h:

```
class Game
{
public:
    virtual Game* copy() const = 0;
    virtual int cur_player() const = 0;
    ...
};
```

TicTacToe.h:

```
class TicTacToe : public Game
{
public:
    virtual Game* copy() const;
    virtual int cur_player() const;
    ...
};
```

TicTacToe.cpp:

```
Game* TicTacToe::copy()
{
    ...
}

int TicTacToe::cur_player()
{
    ...
}
```

Create your game like this:

```
TicTacToe ttt;
Game* game = &ttt;
Game* nextGame = game->copy(); // this will call TicTacToe::copy
```

If you need to call TicTacToe specific methods, either add them to Game, or try downcasting:

```
TicTacToe* ttt = dynamic_cast<TicTacToe*>(game);
ttt->TTTSpecificMethod();
```

Comment: Raw new and delete is really bad, and so is `static_cast`ing down, it should really be a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm quite new to C++. I have done Java, Python and Ruby for 3-5 years, and a bit of C. But never C++. I'll be careful about cleaning up the allocated memory. And your approach sounds good. Maybe is not worth to use Templates if I can get the job done with one downcast like: `static_cast<TicTacToe*>(game)`.

Comment: As DeadMG suggested, you should probably use a dynamic_cast. But I would definitely do all this without the templates if you can! :)

Comment: @DeadMG, I believe I've addressed your concerns. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @wanstein: Templates are the way to go. Always use resource-managing classes to handle all resources- including memory.

Comment: Why use templates rather than just inherit from some Object class and then do all your memory management using pointer-to-Objects? Wouldn't this improve your compile time significantly?

Comment: @arasmussen: What about your *run* time? Using templates will improve that very significantly. More importantly, templates are guaranteed to be correct. Inheritance is most definitely not. Inheritance should be avoided in all possible cases, it is a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Self-bounding generics (Java) is equalent with Curiously recurring template pattern(C++) via a few modifications.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:
  explicit A(A *temp) {}

public:
  explicit A() : A(static_cast<T*>(this)) {}
  virtual A* function(T *parameter) = 0;
};

class B final : public A<B>
{
public:
    B* function(B *parameter) { return new B(); }
};

class C final
{
};

class D final : public A<C>
{
public: // It occurs compile-time-error
  D* function(C *parameter) { return new D(); }
};

class E final : public A<E>
{
public: //"override" specifier will not be accepted due to signature does not match!
    E* function(E *parameter) override { return new E(); }
};

class F final : public A<B>
{
public: //You can also assign another relative type but type-self
    F* function(B *parameter) { return new F(); }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```